# Jordan Normal Form Proof in Lang

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

In Lang’s third edition of *Linear Algebra* [on page $264$](https://books.google.com/books?id=0DUXym7QWfYC&pg=PA264), I don’t understand the first line of his proof that any nonzero vector space over the complex numbers can be decomposed into the direct sum of $A$ invariant cyclic subspaces, where $A$ is a linear operator.

Here’s Theorem $4.2$, which he   references:

> Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, and let $A:V\to V$ be a linear operator. Let $P(t)$ be a polynomial such that $P(A)=0$, and let $P(t)=(t-\alpha_1)^{m_1}...(t-\alpha_r)^{m_r}$ be its factorization. Then $V=W_1\oplus W_2 \oplus ... \oplus W_r$, where $W_i=\mathrm{Ker}(A-\alpha_iI)^{m_i}.$

And the first line of his proof is:

> By Theorem $4.2$, we may assume without loss of generality there exists a number $\alpha$ and an integer $r\geq 1$ such that $(A-\alpha I)^r=0$.

Where $A$ is the linear operator used in the proof. I just have no clue how this theorem is used at all to show the existence of such numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The point is that because each $W_i$ is an invariant subspace, we can put $A$ in Jordan form by separately putting each restriction $A|_{W_i}$ into Jordan form.

Comment: Yea but where does $(A-\alpha I)^r=0$ come from?

Comment: The invariant subspace is $W_i = \ker(A - \alpha_i I)^{m_i}$. It follows that $A|_{W_i}$ will satisfy $(A|_{W_i} - \alpha I)^r = 0$ with $\alpha_i = \alpha$ and $r = m_i$.

Comment: Hi @BenGrossmann. Once the discussion ends, can you record it in the form of an answer? Best,

Comment: @BenGrossmann Sorry, I don’t really understand what you’re trying to say. That’s just the restriction to $W_i$, how does it make the whole map $A$ over $V$ equal to $0$?

Comment: @MichaelCatliMath It does not make the whole map over $V$ equal to zero. The point is that, for the purposes of the proof, the author is replacing $A$ with $A|_{W_i}$ (because once we can put such a transformation into Jordan form, we can easily generalize to arbitrary transformations). In other words, the author is saying that without loss of generality, we can suppose that $A = T|_{W_i}$ for some transformation $T$.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Will do

Comment: @BenGrossmann That makes a lot more sense. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary of a discussion from the comments:**

The key is that because each $W_i$ is an invariant subspace, we can put $A$ in Jordan form by separately putting each restriction $A|_{W_i}$ into Jordan form. Because these invariant subspaces are given by $W_i = \ker(A - \alpha_i I)^{m_i}$, it must hold that $T = A|_{W_i}$ will satisfy $(T - \alpha I)^r = 0$ with $\alpha_i = \alpha$ and $r = m_i$.

For the purposes of the proof, we consider $A$ to be one of these maps over an invariant subspace rather than taking $A$ to be an arbitrary transformation.

Comment: Quick question: Since every arbitrary map $A$ always has a polynomial $f$ such that $f(A)=0$, and Theorem $4.2$ is true, any nonzero $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is always decomposable into these $W_i$ subspaces. So with that said, does the proof work with $V$ being $W_i$ after this step, since the goal is to put each $W_i$ in Jordan form (i.e. decomposing each $W_i$ into $A$-invariant cyclic subspaces)?

Comment: @MichaelCatliMath I don't understand exactly what you have in mind when you say "$V$ being $W_i$" or "put each $W_i$ in Jordan form", but it sounds like you have the right idea.

Comment: Sorry about that. I mean that whenever Lang references the vector space $V$, he is really talking about a subspace $W_i$ without loss of generality.

Comment: @Michael ...where $W_i$ is an invariant subspace as in Theorem 4.2. That's what I suspected you meant, and yes, that's right.

Comment: Yep! Thank you, I appreciate the help.